# Is it possible for the Keys of a map to be arrays? (Map array error)

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, key

I want to make a map which has arrays of the form int[27] as Keys, So I tried the following:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
map<int[27] ,int> mapa;
int n[27];
int main(){
    mapa[n]++;
}
```

But I get an error, is it because arrays can't be used as key type for a map?
What can I do in this case? Would it work if I used a vector instead of an array?

---

Is this the suggestion?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
map<array<int,27> ,int> mapa;
int n[27];
int main(){
    mapa[n]++;
}
```

---

This is the version that works:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
map<array<int,27>, int> mapa;
array<int,27> v;
int main(){
    mapa[v]++;
    printf("%d\n",mapa[v]);
}
```

Comment: Try `map<std::array<int,27> ,int> mapa;` instead.

Comment: It says mapa was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Add `#include <array>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I get an error, is it because arrays can't be a map?

I think you actually mean *map key type*. No, raw arrays can't be used as keys, because there's no intrinsic less operator declared for them.

> What can I do in this case? Would it work if I used a vector instead of an array?

Yes, you can use `std::vector<int>` as key. Even better yet `std::array<int,27>`, if you know it's a fixed size of 27.

The exact documentation how `std::less()` works with `std::array` can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp).

Alternatively you can provide your own comparison algorithm as @NathanOliver was pointing out.

---

> Is this the suggestion?
>
> ```
> #include <cstdio>
> #include <map>
> using namespace std;
> map<array<int,27> ,int> mapa;
> int n[27];
> int main(){
>     mapa[n]++;
> }
> ```

Almost. You need

```
std::array<int,27> n;
```

there of course, there's no automatic conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much! But when I run the code that I just added recently to the body of my question it marks an error in the line mapa[n]++ saying mapa  was not declared in this scope, can this be fixed?

Comment: Look at my comment on your question, you have to include the corresponding header of course.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, I just have a couple of more questions, thank you for your help, it has been awesome. So apparently I am using a different kind of array now? to get it to work I had to make n an array of the new kind.

Comment: I uploaded the final version that worked, It didn't work when I used int n[27]. I had to declare a new object of type array, are they different things? Also, I had to compile using a modified g++. These objects only exist in c++11 right?

Comment: @dREaM _"These objects only exist in c++11 right?"_ Yes, that's already pointed out in the reference documentation link.

Comment: One last question: would int n[27]; work or would I need array<int,27> n;  ?

Comment: I've already pointed out in my answer, there's no automatic conversion, you would need it.

Answer (score 0):

This would compile:

```
map<int *,int> mapa
```

But it is not what you want...
Arrays are almost the same as pointers, therefore you cannot build a map of arrays. It would only compare the pointer in memory when retrieving/setting its value, not its content.

Comment: _@MtCS_ _"... therfore you cannot build a map of arrays."_ Well, you were proven wrong here.